# php wget and priovide a time for last modified

Tags: wget

I know that wget has an -N function, (and also a timestamping option for non-header sending protocols like FTP), but how would I specify a time and date for wget.

For example; I don't want to compare local and remote files, I would like to directly specify a time and date for wget to use. I know the following is not correct, it just serves the purpose of the example:

```
wget -N **--jan-2-2013-05:00** r ftp://user:myPassword@ftp.example.com/public_html
```

Is it possible to give wget a timestamp to use when checking last modified?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps you didn't read the original post. I know about the timestamping option, but that only compares local vs. remote files. I need to directly specify a date if possible...

Comment: You could use `touch` to modifiy the timestamp on the local file but thats sounds like a bad idea. Why is the php tag there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not such option.

Timestamping behavior is pretty automatic in wget. When you use --timestamping or -N option then the file will not get downloaded if:

a) The file already exists locally

AND

b) The file has the same size locally and remotely

AND

c) The timestamp of the remote file is equal or older than the timestamp of the local file (in http it compares against the Last-Modified header)

so you can emulate the behavior you are asking if you:

1. Create the files you are going to download with the same size as
   those in the remote location (a+b conditions)
2. Touch the files so that they have the timestamp you want (c
   condition)

Example:

for a single file the name which we already know let's say foo.txt of size 7348 that we want to get only newer files after 2013-07-24T14:27 that would be:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=foo.txt bs=1 count=7348
touch -t 201307241427 foo.txt
```

now if you use `wget -N http://url/path/foo.txt` the wget will work like you asked

Comment: I figured as much, are there any other options to find newly modified files against a specified time?

Comment: If you cannot use rsync then use lftp, it has flags -N, --newer-than that is probably what you want. See [http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) for documentation and [https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/21](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/21) for the format of --newer-than.